# IndentationError in Python

Tags: python

I am performing one python program and the part of the code is as follows

```
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    if not data: break
    print "received data:", data
    com = "echo " + data
    print com
    conn.send(data)
conn.close()
```

but when i am trying to execute the code i am getting the following error.

```
    File "server.py", line 17
        com = "echo " + data
        ^
    IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

I am not getting whats wrong with the code above.

Comment: Make sure you use the same indentation character (space or tab) and the same level of indentaion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check that you either consistently have tabs or spaces not a mix of both.